# Words with the same consonants

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Each line is a clue for two words that share the same consonants, in the same order. As an example, the answer to

> A snake that builds

would be

> constrictor constructor.

.

> 1. An article about being smooth.
> 2. A function that makes you wet.
> 3. The challenge of making something more general.
> 4. Spending too much time thinking about the past.

What are the four pairs of words?

Hint for #1:

> The two words each have 5 consonants. The letter count is (10, 7)

Comment: An article you shouldn't have written: rot13(hajvfr arjf).  An article about being calm: rot13(crnpr cvrpr).  A function to come: rot13(shgher srngher).  Spending too much time thinking about openings: rot13(qrqvpngvba nqvpgvga).

Comment: An article about getting wet: rot13(ovytr oybt).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Man, I should've made more than 4, those are pretty good.

Comment: Well, it was just some of the near misses I came up with while searching for solutions to your clues, that I still liked enough to post.

Comment: Could we maybe get a hint on #1 - it's been driving me crazy.  My latest guess is almost certainly not it.  More like: An article in an HVAC contract: rot13(pbbyf pynhfr).

Comment: @DanielSchepler a hint has been added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. An article about being smooth.

   > <strike>Calamine column?</strike> <strike>Repartee report?</strike> Continuity content?
2. A function that makes you wet.

   > <strike>Sine sauna?</strike> <strike>Pirate party? Porpoise purpose?</strike> wolfram42 got it: sqrt squirt.
3. The challenge of making something more general.

   > Abstraction obstruction.
4. Spending too much time thinking about the past.

   > Wasteful wistful.

Comment: Alright! 1 down 3 to go

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you found an interesting alternative for #2, but not what I intended.

Comment: You got #4 correct.

Comment: #1 and #2 are incorrect. wolfram42 got #2

Comment: Sorry, still incorrect

Comment: Yes, you got #1! I'll accept your answer since you got 3/4

Answer (score 7):

answer for 4:$ $  $ $  $ $

> Linger Longer

Comment: Good answer, but not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Answer for number 3?

> Burden broaden

Comment: Wow, good alternative answer

Answer (score 4):

1. An article about being smooth:

   > Published Polished
2. A function that makes you wet.

   > Square Squirt  or alternatively Sqrt Squirt

And taken from @DanielShelper

3. The challenge of making something more general.

   > Abstraction obstruction.
4. Spending too much time thinking about the past.

   > Wasteful wistful?

Comment: Square is missing a letter.

Comment: #1 does not work because "polished" is missing a "b"

Comment: wasteful and wistful were the accepted answers despite "wistful" missing an "e". Other alternative answers accepted by @Riley also have extra letters.

Comment: @wolfram42 the vowels don't matter; in the original question, he states that the two words have the same consonants in the same order

Comment: Ok, I autochanged the word "consonants" with "letters" in my head. thanks for the clarification

Comment: You got #2 after the "or alternatively..."

Answer (score 0):

2. a function that makes you wet

   > Pipe-pop. when a pipe bursts, water (or other liquids) are expelled, making anyone nearby wet

Comment: Where does the "function" part come in?