# More Consonant Sameness

Tags: riddle, wordplay, anagram

Each answer will have two words with the same consonants in the same order.
An example, for the newcomers:

> When Spies Collide

which is of course a

> collusion collision.

Based on [Riley's recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64354/words-with-the-same-consonants/64361).

Now for the actual puzzle:

> 1. (4, 4) (l)
> 2. vegan insult (4, 5) (r)
> 3. satellite (5, 5) (t)
> 4. performer permanence (5, 6) (r)
> 5. cow suit pun (5, 6) (r)
> 6. new chicken tarantella (3, 5) (g)
> 7. fluffy ticket (6, 8) (n)
> 8. The wrath of grapes (6, 5) (n)
> 9. Einstein's Leftovers (6, 6) (t)
> 10. Presidential Seasoning (6, 7) (n)

And the first letters of each answer will be an anagram of the answer to this one final challenge:

> Cats would be __________s.

Helpful information:

- Every answer is a noun.
- You won't be able to solve the last clue without the other answers probably.
- Most of the answers are humorous, and **will fit the clues clearly**. If it's questionable, it's probably wrong.
- The pairs of numbers after the clues are the letter counts of the answers.
- The letters after the clues are the last consonants of the answers.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: (not a downvoter) Why require the initials to be anagrammed as opposed to listing the clues in the correct order?

Comment: @noedne It makes it harder to get the clues from guessing the final answer. The final answer's purpose is to rule out alternative answers mostly. If people have trouble, I might give away the order of the clues in the last challenge

Comment: "permanence" means the act/quality of being "permanent" right?

Comment: @NL628 yes, that is correct

Comment: *Very* nice of you to add the letter counts! :) Thought I was going crazy: "Were those there the *entire time???*"

Comment: LOL @Chowzen same tho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.Sunglasses Emoji

> Cool Clue

2.vegan insult

> Tree Eater (Rubio)

3.satellite

> Orbit Robot

4.performer permanence

> Tenor Tenure (Rubio)

5.cow suit pun

> Utter Attire (hagfy)

6.new chicken tarantella

> egg gigue

7.fluffy ticket

> Cotton citation (user48034)

8.The wrath of grapes

> Raisin arson (generalcrispy)

9.Einstein's Leftovers

> Astute Estate (hagfy)

10.presidential seasoning

> Reagan Oregano

Final answer:

> Cats would be **cuter actors**.

Comment: All right so far

Comment: If you guess something with one word correct, I will say something along the lines of "that is very close"

Comment: hmm @AustinWeaver what's the final thing though? I found a bunch of anagrams but I can't tell which one's right. Is it two words or one word in the blank?

Comment: Noedne's guess for the final answer is correct.

Comment: Lol I got it seconds before you wrote that comment :D

Answer (score 7):

7.fluffy ticket:

> Cotton citation

9.Einstein's Leftovers:

> Astute estate?

5.cow suit pun:

> Utter attire?

Comment: Correct! Good job.

Comment: you're correct again

Comment: Wow, really?  How about my guess for 5?

Comment: that seems to fit the bill, right?

Comment: Nice!  I think that's all of them then.  NL628 got most of them, and noedne seems to have the final answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm going to give out the bounty... both you and NL628 got three clues

Comment: I'd go with NL628 then.  I'm new to this whole thing and they really got the ball rolling.

Comment: Nah you need help on your way to higher rep. A good riddle solver needs more rep to contribute more to the community. @AustinWeaver +100 for hagfy please :D

Comment: @AustinWeaver Mind you, not rewarding the bounty until the very end is a good idea, as it brings more attention to your question :D

Comment: I'd argue further, but since you have more rep, you'd probably win. =D  ...I'm only in it for the puzzles though!

Answer (score 6):

I'm still struggling, but I'm going to toss in one of my guesses here in hopes that it helps.

8. The wrath of grapes:

   > raisin arson

Comment: Good job, that is correct.

Answer (score 6):

2. > Tree Eater.

4. > Tenor Tenure.

5. > Udder Dudery ?!

9. > Albert [no idea; can't find a single word that fits here]

Comment: 2 and 4 are correct, 5 is not.

Comment: "albert" is not the first word for 9.

Answer (score 4):

6. new chicken tarantella

> egg gogo

10. Presidential seasoning

> Reagan Oregano

2. vegan insult

> Beanhead Bonehead ??

5. cow suit pun (5, 6) (r)

> mooer moaner  - I know... that "n" doesn't belong,  I just thought it might trigger thoughts for someone.

Comment: 10 is correct, 6 is very close, 2 is wrong.

Comment: What?! 2 is amazing!!!

Answer (score 3):

7. fluffy ticket:

   > Ruffle raffle
8. The wrath of grapes:

   > Violent Valiant (Valiant is a type of grape)

Comment: Nope, nice try though. Notice that that is an adjective, where the answer will be a noun (What is "the wrath of grapes"?)

Comment: if everything is two words, wouldn't the answers be mostly an adjective followed by a noun?

Comment: Yes, they are actually all nouns (I'll edit this into the question).

Comment: 7 is also incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

> 5. <s>Steer suitor (Steer courtesy of Rubio)</s> Udder ------
> 9. <s>Albert ------</s>
> Final answer: Cats would be **cuter actor**s

Comment: Also incorrect. The first word isn't steer.

Answer (score 2):

Number 2. Vegan insult

> Satan seitan  (seitan is another word for wheat gluten)

Comment: Incorrect, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try
1-  (4, 4)

> Cool Clue?

2-Vegan Insult

> Snob Snub?  [God](https://media1.tenor.com/images/237788f1d2bb5767d0d2fe0a7cade09b/tenor.gif?itemid=8171795) Goad?

4-Performer Permanence

> <s>Hot Hit or [Bared Broad](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2007/07/23/knocked-up-gives-nudityba_n_57471.html) (funny!)</s>
>  Oscar Secure

8-The Wrath of Grapes

> Mad [Mud](http://www.mudhouse.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/NV-Mud-House-Marlborough-Sauvignon-Blanc_3-1-768x2633.jpg)?

9-Einstein's Leftorvers (6,6)

> Genius Agains

Comment: 1 is correct, the others are all incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First off, thanks to other answerers for helping me with guesses to these.

> 1.  (4, 4) (l) **cool clue**
>   2. vegan insult (4, 5) (r) - **tree eater**
>   3. satellite (5, 5) (t) - **orbit robot**
>   4. performer permanence (5, 6) (r) - **tenor tenure**
>   5. cow suit pun (5, 6) (r) - **utter attire**
>   6. new chicken tarantella (3, 5) (g) - **egg gigue**
>   7. fluffy ticket (6, 8) (n) - **cotton citation**
>   8. The wrath of grapes (6, 5) (n) - **raisin arson**
>   9. Einstein's Leftovers (6, 6) (t) - **astute estate**
>  10. Presidential Seasoning (6, 7) (n) - **Reagan Oregano**

And for the final challenge... the only thing I could find that fits well...

> **cuter actors**.

Answer (score 0):

Joining the party late:

9:

> Albert Labrat?

<s>I suspect I have the final answer:

**DOUBLE SPOILER**</s>

> <s>Acrobat.</s>`TYPO` Acrobatic. Leaving letters A, B and I for the first words of the remaining clues.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect.

Comment: Also, the final answer has the whole "same consonants" thing going on too

Comment: Whoops, just saw your comment after I edited. More to think about. A FURRY CLAWver PURRzle indeed. (I'm not sorry)